# Counting average from two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying get the average from two select queries. In the first select i'm counting all "votes" per district, now i want to devide it by total sum of votes in voivodeship(It can have more than one district)

```
select void.name, d.name, t.name, COUNT(v.idvotes) as "Percent of votes"
    from voivodeship void, politicialteam t, votes v, candidates c, person p, district d
    where c.idcandidates = v.idcandidates
        and p.idperson = c.idperson
        and c.idpoliticialteam = t.idpoliticialteam
        and void.idvoivodeship = d.idvoivodeship
        and c.iddistrict = d.iddistrict
    GROUP by d.name ORDER by void.name ASC 

SELECT Count(vo.idvotes)
    from votes vo, candidates c, district d, voivodeship v
    where d.idvoivodeship = v.idvoivodeship
        and d.iddistrict = c.iddistrict
        and vo.idcandidates = c.idcandidates
    GROUP by v.name
```

[image: total of district]

[image: total of voivodeship]

Total for "dolnośląskie": 119987

In my example i want merge this two queries to get result 40038/119987, 40078/119987 etc..

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this result in two different way, depending on your DBMS.

1. If your DBMS supports Extended SQL queries, you should try to get a partition on void.name and aggregate the result in order to compute your percentage:

```
SELECT void.name, 
       d.name, 
       t.name, 
       COUNT(v.idvotes) as "Percent of votes",
       COUNT(v.idvotes)/SUM(COUNT(v.idvoted))*100 OVER (PARTITION BY void.name) as "Votes percentage"
FROM voivodeship void, politicialteam t, votes v, candidates c, person p, district d
where c.idcandidates = v.idcandidates and
      p.idperson = c.idperson and
      c.idpoliticialteam = t.idpoliticialteam and
      void.idvoivodeship = d.idvoivodeship and
      c.iddistrict = d.iddistrict
GROUP BY d.name, void.name
ORDER BY void.name ASC
```

2. If your DBMS does not support Extended SQL, you can achieve the same result nesting the two queries:

```
SELECT void.name, 
       d.name, 
       t.name, 
       COUNT(v.idvotes) as "Percent of votes",
       COUNT(v.idvotes)/(
         SELECT Count(vo.idvotes) 
         FROM votes vo1, candidates c1, district d1, voivodeship v1
         WHERE d1.idvoivodeship = v1.idvoivodeship and 
               d1.iddistrict = c1.iddistrict and 
               vo1.idcandidates = c1.idcandidates and
               d1.name = d.name
         GROUP BY v.name
       )*100 AS "Percentage of votes"
FROM voivodeship void, politicialteam t, votes v, candidates c, person p, district d
where c.idcandidates = v.idcandidates and
      p.idperson = c.idperson and
      c.idpoliticialteam = t.idpoliticialteam and
      void.idvoivodeship = d.idvoivodeship and
      c.iddistrict = d.iddistrict
GROUP BY d.name, void.name
ORDER BY void.name ASC
```

N.B. In the last solution you can merge the queries adding another JOIN condition on the nested query such as

```
d1.name = d.name
```